# Fetching iCloudKit records older than 24 hours

Tags: swift, date, icloud, predicate

I am sorry have a stupid easy question. I want to list all records created that are older than 24 hours. The query field for the creation date is set on the dashboard. I have this code... but I cannot seem to get my head around the problem.

I got this code ...

```
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.blah")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
// 24 hours ago
    let date = NSDate(timeInterval: -60.0 * 1440, sinceDate: NSDate())
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate < %@", date)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Collection", predicate: predicate)
```

But this gets me all the records that have been created in the last 24 hours; I don't want them, I want all the records that are older than 24 hours. My record contains only one field, and that is an asset. Starting to think that is my problem in part...

[image]

The index size if deployed doesn't look promising does it? 0 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer to my problem. This code is good; my mistake was in selecting only the recordIDs when I was choosing records. I needed to select the meta data too.

readerOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        readerOperation.desiredKeys = ["record.recordID.recordName","record.creationDate"];

```
    readerOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
        self.records2Erase.append(record.recordID)
    }
    readerOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, error) in
            if error != nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            } else {                 
                print("records2Erase since \(date) \(self.records2Erase)")
            }


    }
```